# My main hard drive (the one C:\ is on) is showing as raw

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, partition-recovery, raw

My main hard drive (the one C:\ is on) is showing as raw.  I got a bluescreen (wish I had recorded what it said on it before I restarted, but it's probably a moot point now) and tried to restart, but the laptop froze before Windows loaded.

I did some diagnostic stuff using a recovery drive and it became apparent that something had happened to C (it was showing as a Raw drive named D).

I reassigned the drive letters back to the correct ones but I can't find any way of indicating that the drive is not raw.  The partitions are all there according to DISKPART (Recovery 300mb, System 100mb, Reserved 128mb, Primary 237gb, Recovery 663mb), and the System partition is still formatted, as when I list the volumes, I get a FAT32 with 100MB, but everything else is raw.

Much of the drive is Bitlocker encrypted.  I know there are 3rd party tools that claim to be able to recover things, but I am wary that it will render the drive inoperable, even if it will get my data back.  I have most of my data backed up, I just want a functioning OS that has all of my applications.

**UPDATE:**

I am still trying to repair my laptop and I have been trying to re-image things using a recent system image that was made by an automatic backup.  The problem is I get a message saying that a disk could not be restored (0x80042402) image below. I tried Macrium Reflect, but after many hours of painstakingly slow loading, it said it couldn't find an image. Could the reason be because my version of Windows is the Enterprise version, and that version is not on the repair disk (doing `dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:"e:\sources\install.esd` indicated every flavor but Enterprise)?

***Everything in the recovery environment is incredibly slow!!!***

[image: error message that comes up when I try to re-image my machine]

Comment: I think I am going to use system restore, but I only want to restore the disk that C:\ is on (my SSD), not my other HDD (E:\) that the majority of my data is on because that is fine.  On the last screen in the "Re-Image your computer", window, under: `EFI System Partition, E:,C:, \\?\\Volume{2ddab17-.....d9b}`; can I just get rid of the "E:\" reference?  I already checked "exclude disks...", but I have a suspicion that that just excludes those disks from being formatted, but the data on them will still be copied (or more likely, the recover process will fail).

Comment: If that won't work, I there a way I can use wbadmin to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your disk has experienced a catastrophic failure.
The question now is whether it's dead or can be recovered.

As your data is mostly backed up, you should format the disk and reinstall
Windows from USB.
During the installation, format the disk using slow format, so every sector
will be rewritten.

If the installation succeeds, use `chkdsk` to check if the number of
bad sectors is not too excessive. Afterward, check the SMART attributes
of the disk to see the number of errors.
If you have no product for this, you could use
[Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy).
If you need help understanding the attributes, post a screenshot
inside your post.

If there is a large number of errors, the disk should be replaced.

Comment: If his drive experienced a catastrophic failure then I guess it should be replaced!

Comment: I already did ChkDsk and there were no errors.  Reinstalling the OS would get rid of all my applications!  I know how to reinstall Windows, what I am looking for support on is how to make windows understand that the volumes are ntfs and not raw.

Comment: @SomeoneElse - Since you were using BitLocker. **You cant**

Comment: I am able to unlock things no  problem though - anyway I think at this point I am going to risk using my backup image and hope for the best

Answer (score 0):

I thought this was a classic case of partition corruption but then you mentioned bitlocker. If there is an issue with your drive/partition you can't do much about it if your drive is encrypted. You will need to decrypt it first. Then you can scan your drive for problems and try and restore data. Since your are doing this for your C drive you may need to do this from safe mode or another bootable disk.

**Unlock the drive**

`manage-bde -unlock C: -pw`

**Turn off Encryption**

Start by opening a command prompt as administrator. Type:

`manage-bde -off C:`

This should disable the encryption on your C: drive. The drive letter will be different if you are booting off a boot CD.

To check encryption status, you can also use

`manage-bde -status`

**Try to fix the drive**

Now that encryption is off you should be able to work on the drive. We can try and use the stock BitLocker Repair Tool to recover your data. Run:

`repair-bde X: Y: -pw –Force`

This is where X: is a disk with the BitLocker data, and Y: is a disk to extract the recovered decrypted data to.
Another option to try and save your drive is by running a chkdisk. Being your disk is decrypted you should be able to run this command now.

`chkdsk c: /f /r`

See if that fixes it. Being the problem is your boot drive C: your gonna have some fun. If all else fails, you can try 3rd party software. Or at that point, you may just end up formatting your hard drive and reinstalling windows. You could also boot off a windows CD and try a windows repair or boot to a last know good configuration (when you hit F8 at boot). But again, if your drive is still encrypted nothing will work. It will still show raw. That is how an encrypted drive protects you. That is the key issue here.

Comment: As I'm already doing all this using a recovery drive, I am pretty sure I already unlocked things when I first opened the cmd prompt, I at least entered the recovery key when I clicked on the CMD option in the menu (although I also had already used Shift+F10 because I was impatient).  I tried `manage-bde –status` but it is taking forever to give me any results (recovery drive is incredibly slow!)

Comment: Entering the BitLocker Recovery code does not disable nor suspend BitLocker protection

Comment: Thanks Ramhound. I've updated my answer. You need to use the -off flag.

Comment: @SomeoneElse You have to unlock it, then decrypt it before you can try to fix it. If you don't decrypt it, it will continue to appear as raw and you won't be able to work with it.